# Capybara::Element Not Found for <select> populated by onchange of previous element

Tags: rspec, capybara

I get the following error when I run `bundle exec rspec` for my feature test for a form:

```
 Failure/Error: select('Boston Commons - Vacation English', :from => 'school_application_program')
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find option "Boston Commons - Vacation English"
```

Here is the snippet of my scenario from my feature spec:

```
select('Boston Commons', :from => 'school_application_fls_center')
select('Boston Commons - Vacation English', :from => 'school_application_program')
```

The second line fails.

In my development environment I visit the same route that the scenario visits, 
perform the previous selection, and then confirm that `school_application_program` is the id of the `<select>` tag and that the option name is the exact same as the one I am checking.

My only guess, is that for some reason, my javascript `onchange` function is not properly populating the `<select>` tag, but that doesn't make a whole lot of sense given that the feature spec should mirror the development environment exactly.

The onchange event is being bound to the `<select>` tag immediately preceding `school_application_program` and resets the options for `school_application_program`

Here is the javascript that populated my `school_application_program` `<select>`

```
 $("#school_application_fls_center").change(function(){
var center_id = document.getElementById("school_application_fls_center").value;
var formdata = {center: center_id}; 
$.ajax({
    url: "/application/get_programs_for_center",
    type: "POST",
    datatype: 'json',
    data: formdata,
    success: function(response){
      var options = $("#school_application_program"); 
      removeOptions(document.getElementById("school_application_program"));
      $.each(response.programs, function(i,item) {
        options.append($("<option />").val(response.programs[i].id).text(response.programs[i].name)); 
      });
    }
});
});
```

This is a shot from my development environment, showing the form, after I have done the behavior that the spec does manually, at the point where the test fails.

[image]

Comment: Is that feature spec marked to use the `js: true` flag? Or maybe capybara isn't waiting for the ajax call to return before running your expectation.

Comment: neither is the case. Do you know how I can do either of those things?

Comment: The feature spec isn't going to run the ajax call unless you tell it to use javascript. check out the section 'Running specs with Javascript' in http://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-we-test-rails-applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that was required was to enable Javascript via adding the `:js => true` flag when the `scenario` was defined, like so:

```
scenario 'happy path that uses AJAX', :js=>true do
   #etc.
end
```